# JTable not repainted after deleting a row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

AdminFrame.java

```
package com.sorcerok;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

public class AdminFrame extends JFrame {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton delete, change;
    private JTable usersTable;
    private static final int WIDTH = 510;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 300;
    private List<User> list;
    private MyTableModel model;

    public AdminFrame(JFrame frame) {
        super("Просмотр пользователей");
        setResizable(false);
        this.frame = frame;
        frame.setVisible(false);


        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        delete = new JButton("Удалить");
        delete.setBounds(310, 230, 121, 30);
        change = new JButton("Изменить");
        change.setBounds(50, 230, 121, 30);


        list = new ArrayList<>(Authorisation.userMap.values());

        model = new MyTableModel(list);

        usersTable = new JTable(model);
        JTableHeader header = usersTable.getTableHeader();
        header.setForeground(Color.black);
        header.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(usersTable);

        sp.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 90);

        panel.add(delete);
        panel.add(change);
        panel.add(sp);

        add(panel);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void dispose() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
        super.dispose();
    }

    public void deleteFromTable() {

        delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int row = usersTable.getSelectedRow();
                if (getSelectedUser(row) != null) {
                    Authorisation.userMap.remove(getSelectedUser(row).getName());
                    list.remove(getSelectedUser(row));
                    System.out.println(list);
                    Registration.writeToFile();

                    model.removeRow(row);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public User getSelectedUser(int index) {
        index = usersTable.getSelectedRow();
        if (isSelectedUser(index)) {
            String name = (String) usersTable.getValueAt(index, 1);
            return getUser(name);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean isSelectedUser(int index) {
        if (index < 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public User getUser(String name) {
        for (User u : list) {
            if (name.equals(u.getName())) {
                return u;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<User> list;

        private MyTableModel(List<User> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener listener) {
        }

        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return String.class;
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {

            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return "№";
                case 1:
                    return "Логин";
                case 2:
                    return "Пароль";
            }
            return "";
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            User user = list.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return ++rowIndex;
                case 1:
                    return user.getName();
                case 2:
                    return user.getPassword();

            }
            return "";
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return false;
        }

        public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener listener) {
        }

        public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        }

        public void removeRow(int row) {

            fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
            fireTableStructureChanged();
            System.out.println("Deleted by AbstractTableModel Table Model");

        }
    }
}
```

And invoked method in other class

```
AdminFrame af = new AdminFrame(frame);
af.deleteFromTable();
```

When a lot of elements in the table and there is scrolling, that is, press to delete a row, the row immediately removed from Arralist but not removed from the table, and if you use to scroll, the record immediately disappears. Same functions without this method model.removeRow(row); What's wrang?

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, that's the exclusive task of a suitable LayoutManager

Comment: First, I want to fix delete function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your table model does not support `TableModelListeners`**, that's why the table can't observe changes on the model.

Your **TableModel** is supposed to **notify** the `TableModelListeners` **when it changes** (when rows are added, removed or refreshed). 
When setting the model on the table, the table will add a `TableModelListener` to **observe** the model. Once the model changes, it fires a `TableModelEvent` (by calling `tableChanged(TableModelEvent)` on all listeners). The `JTable` will then receive this notification and revalidate and repaint the table content to adapt to the changes.

**In your concrete case:**
You've overridden the `add|removeTableModelListener()` methods, so **no listeners can be registered**. Just remove those two methods on your model, and let the `DefaultTableModel`'s implementation of those methods handle it.

Comment: Thanks you very much its works when i used DefaultTableModel and invoke removeRow method from DefaultTableModel